# CIDR Address is not within CIDR Address from VPC - /25

Tags: amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-vpc

I am trying to create two subnets based on 10.0.0.0/25, my VPC range.
I should be able to create one subnet 10.0.0.0/25 and another 10.0.0.128/25.

I am able to create the first one.  For the second one, I receive a message of CIDR Address not within CIDR of VPC.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Thanks JD D for your answer.

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains how to subnet, and you will see where you have gone wrong in your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 10.0.0.0/25 (128 IPs) CIDR for your VPC and want two subnets, they need to be /26 (64 IPs).

The CIDRs for the two subnets should be:

```
10.0.0.0/26
10.0.0.64/26
```